# Set the update rate for a method

Tags: java

How can I handle the "update rate" of a method, let's say I want to run a method every 200 milliseconds, how would I do that in an very accurate way without using `Thread.sleep(...)` methods?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what you mean by the "update rate" of a method?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by accurate? What variation is acceptable given 200 ms is likely to an arbitrary choice?

Comment: Yes 200 ms is arbitrary time and a variation of 10% would be acceptable

Answer (score 3):

Java is (normally) not a real-time system. If you need to call a method precisely every 200 miliseconds, you will run into problems. If some deviation is ok, use a scheduler like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for this.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand your question - you want to "execute" a method every 200 milliseconds and you do not want to use the Thread.sleep() stuff.

The solution to your problem lies in the Timer/TimerTask class combination. Please read http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html

Have a look at the section "Performing a Task Repeatedly" on the above link.

Answer (score 2):

I would try using [ScheduleExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) Its a built in library with fairly high accuracy. (It uses nano timings where available instead of mill-second timing which older libraries use)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a way of repeatedly executing the same task with a set time interval. In that case you are looking for [java.util.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [java.util.TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).